# javascript code works only with breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run some async code in function(1) but I am unable to get the output of the function(1), which I need to use as input for function(2). it returns 'undefined.
however, if I put a breakpoint at the return statement of function(1) it starts working & stops again when I remove the breakpoint.
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

```
oFile = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
var myFunc = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return resolve(S4HanaFioriAccelerator.common.handleListResponse(oFile));
    });
};
myFunc().then(function success(data) {
    console.log(data);
});



handleListResponse: function(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    data = e.target.result;
    results = [];
    cfb = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
    });

    cfb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        sCSV = XLS.utils.make_csv(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);
        oJS = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);
        for(var i= 0; i < oJS.length; i++){
            results.unshift(oJS[jsRowCount].Data);
        }
        console.log(results);
    });
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hello"); 
    return results;
}, 3000);       
}
```

output in console: 
undefined                                        file1.js
["Student1", "Student2"]                         file2.js
Hello                                            file2.js

expected output:
["Student1", "Student2"]                         file2.js
Hello                                            file2.js
["Student1", "Student2"]                         file1.js

Comment: What does `myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse()` look like? Does it return a Promise, or an Object/Array? What is `oEvent`?

Comment: Hi Luca,
no, it's a simple function, returns an array. how should I return promise from that function? (if returning promise is mandatory)

Comment: And it's asynchronous? You should read about promises at you favorite place to read about parts of JavaScript ;)

Comment: yes, it makes an async call to read data from an uploaded file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am getting response if I put a breakpoint, so the post you shared is different from my case.

Comment: could you share the code myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse() ; does it generate promise or waht ?

Comment: what does `console.log(myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse)` output.

Comment: console.log(myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse) prints an array: ["Studen1","Student2"] (that is,only when I put a preakpoint at the return statement of myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse)

Comment: I want the the signature of the function not the results. Can you not create a minimal working example of `myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse`.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I am using cloud flare framework to read excel data & convert it into an array. myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse(oEvent) is the function where I am reading the uploaded excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your function async by returning a promise that will, when completed return data from your function. Then you can catch an resolve you data below.

```
var myFunc = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var data = myNameSpace.common.handleListResponse(oEvent);
        return resolve(data);
    });
};

myFunc().then(function success(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help Mirko, I tried the sample that you provided but I still am getting  'undefined' without break point & expected array with break point.

Comment: Can you supply code for function of yours that returns a list ?

Comment: I have edited my post, it is having all the code that I am using in the app. I still can't understand why is it still printing 'undefined', while putting a console.log in 'handleListResponse' shows that values are generated as expected

Comment: FileReader is also async by itself. Try this please, replace it in code :  
      return resolve(myNamespace.common.handleListResponse(evt1));

Comment: tried, still the same. code is exactly the same as I have shared in the post. I am out of ideas on this, I tried a lot of things but I still am unable to make it work.